# Is there a way to use TLS 1.2 in a MongoDB connection in a DOTNET AWS Lambda?

Tags: .net, mongodb, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, tls1.2

I'm reading around the TLS 1.2 is only supported in .NET Framework >= 4. My code is a AWS lambda function in C#. The newest .NET framework available is 2.1, but i've read there's no support for TLS 1.2. I need to connect to a MongoDB which uses this type of security, is there any workaround possible?, an extra package package maybe? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> The newest .NET framework available is 2.1

You may have mistaken [.NET Core](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Core) with [.NET Framework](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework).

`.NET Core` is a free and open-source managed software framework for Windows, macOS and Linux. `.NET Core` uses [openssl](https://www.openssl.org/) for TLS/SSL support, and TLS version 1.2 has been supported on openssl for a while.

`.NET Framework` is a software framework developed by Microsoft that runs primarily on Microsoft Windows. `.NET Framework` 4.5 and higher supports TLS v1.2. (default in 4.6)

Amazon announced on July 2018 that [AWS Lambda supports .NET Core v2.1](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/06/lambda-supports-dotnetcore-twopointone/).